# How can i declare the callback of a MQTT client inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback, mqtt

I have the following code in my function onActivityCreated. The SDK throws an error with the client.setCallback() it requires the name of the class. Nonetheless, i am working inside a fragment.

```
String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
final MqttAndroidClient client = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"tcp://test.mosquitto.org", clientId);
    try {
        IMqttToken token = client.connect();
        token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                // We are connected
                Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess");
                showToast("Connected");
                //Subscribing to a topic door/status on broker.hivemq.com
                final Activity activity = getActivity();
                client.setCallback( activity.this );
```

Comment: Please provide the complete, exact error message that you see (as thrown by the SDK).
Also, has your class (Fragment) implemented the interface [MqttCallback](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttCallback.html) ?

Comment: The error provided by the SDK is "Class name required". I need to get the name of the fragment's parent class somehow. Yes, it is.

Comment: According to the documentation, `setCallback` method requires a `Callback` parameter. Also, see a sample [here](https://github.com/jeffprestes/AndroidMQTTDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/eclipse/paho/android/service/MqttAndroidClient.java).

Comment: Yes, you have to use the activity to make that callback. Just as you do in an activity. Your answer does not really imply more than the obvious.

Comment: Sorry but I don't see you using a Callback anywhere here. I just saw a github sample for Push Notifications using Mqtt in a Fragment and this is what the guy has written - `client.setCallback(new PushCallback(getActivity()));` See [link](https://github.com/sjtudclab/smartcity-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/sjtu/dclab/smartcity/ui/fragment/ContactsFragment.java).